# R Using case_when to track changes in a column by group

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, case-when

I have a dataset of course enrollment where I am trying to track whether students dropped, added, or retained a course throughout the semester and identify their enrollment 'path'. I.e. I want to record if they were enrolled in BIOL101 and dropped it to take BIOL202. My dataframe looks like this:

```
YRTR    TECH_ID COU_ID  SUBJ    COU_NBR GENDER  RACE    sub_cou     status     path
20173   108      217    MUSC    2231    Male    White   MUSC 2231   retained
20173   108      218    MUSC    2281    Male    White   MUSC 2281   retained
20173   8429     574    ECON    2201    Male    White   ECON 2201   retained
20173   8429     720    BUSN    2120    Male    White   BUSN 2120   retained
20173   9883     60     ECON    2202    Male    White   ECON 2202   added
20173   15515    95     PHIL    1102    Female  White   PHIL 1102   retained
20183   8207     478    ART     1102    Female  White   ART 1102    retained
20183   8207     1306   ART     1130    Female  White   ART 1130    added
20183   8207     403    ART     1125    Female  White   ART 1125    dropped
```

I am trying to fill in the column on the far right, "path". The idea is that if a student is retained in a course like in the first row, the path would read `2231->2231`. Specifically I am looking at course transfers **WITHIN** subjects. So, at the end of the data set, ID 8207 would have one path that looked like `1102->1102`  and another path that looked like `1125->1130`

I initially tried splitting the dataframe into two dataframes (one before, and one after the drop period) and then rejoining them like so:

`data5 <- merge(x=post_drop, y=pre_drop, by=c("TECH_ID", "YRTR", "SUBJ"), all=TRUE)`

And then using case_when to assign the path:

```
data5$status.x=="retained" ~ paste0(data5$COU_NBR.x, "->", data5$COU_NBR.x),
((data5$status.x=="added") & (data5$status.y=="dropped")) ~ paste0(data5$COU_NBR.y, "->", data5$COU_NBR.x),
((data5$status.x=="dropped") & (data5$status.y=="added")) ~ paste0(data5$COU_NBR.x, "->", data5$COU_NBR.y)                
)
```

But this doesn't get me where I want - it leaves a lot of NAs in paths and also doesn't tell me if a student dropped a course within a subject and didn't register for another (i.e. dropping BIOL101 and not taking another BIOL class) in which case I would want something like `101->NA` or when a class is simply added (i.e. they weren't registered in a BIOL class initially but decided to register for BIOL101) which would be formatted like so `NA->101`

Comment: Please provide the data with `dput`, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED SOLUTION Spetember 27th

Hello again @alexvc Here's a start.  Knowing a little bit about your data.  You forget the case where a student dropped 1 and added 2 in which case the "path" becomes muddled.  I've given you a solution that shows `path` clearly.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data5 %>%
   group_by(YRTR, TECH_ID, SUBJ, status) %>%
   mutate(numbadd =
             case_when(
                status == "added" ~ 1,
                TRUE ~ 0
             ),
          numbdrop =
             case_when(
                status == "dropped" ~ 1,
                       TRUE ~ 0
            ),
          rightside =
             case_when(
                numbadd == 1 ~ paste(COU_NBR, collapse = " and ")
                ),
          leftside =
             case_when(
                numbdrop == 1 ~ paste(COU_NBR, collapse = " and ")
             )
   ) %>%
   group_by(YRTR, TECH_ID, SUBJ) %>%
   mutate(total_add_drop = ifelse(status == "retained", 
                                  0, 
                                  sum(numbadd) + sum(numbdrop))) %>%
   tidyr::fill(leftside, rightside, .direction = "downup") %>%
   group_by(YRTR, TECH_ID, SUBJ, status) %>%
   mutate(PATH =
             case_when(
                status == "retained" ~ paste(COU_NBR, 
                                             COU_NBR, 
                                             sep = " -> "),
                status == "added" & total_add_drop == 1 ~ paste("NA", 
                                                                COU_NBR, 
                                                                sep = " -> "),
                status == "dropped" & total_add_drop == 1 ~ paste(COU_NBR, 
                                                                  "NA", 
                                                                  sep = " -> "),
                total_add_drop >= 2 ~ paste(leftside, 
                                            rightside, 
                                            sep = " -> "),
                TRUE ~ "Theres a problem"
             )) %>%
   arrange(YRTR, TECH_ID) %>%
   select(-COU_ID, -GENDER, -RACE, -rightside, -leftside, -numbadd, -numbdrop, -total_add_drop)

#> # A tibble: 17 x 7
#> # Groups:   YRTR, TECH_ID, SUBJ, status [13]
#>     YRTR TECH_ID SUBJ  COU_NBR sub_cou   status   PATH                          
#>    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>    <chr>                         
#>  1 20173     108 MUSC     2231 MUSC 2231 retained 2231 -> 2231                  
#>  2 20173     108 MUSC     2281 MUSC 2281 retained 2281 -> 2281                  
#>  3 20173    3889 ECON     2202 ECON 2202 dropped  2202 -> NA                    
#>  4 20173    8429 ECON     2201 ECON 2201 retained 2201 -> 2201                  
#>  5 20173    8429 BUSN     2120 BUSN 2120 retained 2120 -> 2120                  
#>  6 20173    9883 ECON     2202 ECON 2202 added    NA -> 2202                    
#>  7 20173   15515 PHIL     1102 PHIL 1102 retained 1102 -> 1102                  
#>  8 20183    8207 ART      1102 ART 1102  retained 1102 -> 1102                  
#>  9 20183    8207 ART      1130 ART 1130  added    1125 -> 1130 and 2345         
#> 10 20183    8207 ART      2345 ART 2345  added    1125 -> 1130 and 2345         
#> 11 20183    8207 ART      1125 ART 1125  dropped  1125 -> 1130 and 2345         
#> 12 20183    8209 ART      2345 ART 2345  added    1125 -> 2345                  
#> 13 20183    8209 ART      1125 ART 1125  dropped  1125 -> 2345                  
#> 14 20183    8270 PSYC     1001 PSYC 1001 dropped  1001 and 1002 -> 1003 and 1004
#> 15 20183    8270 PSYC     1003 PSYC 1003 added    1001 and 1002 -> 1003 and 1004
#> 16 20183    8270 PSYC     1002 PSYC 1002 dropped  1001 and 1002 -> 1003 and 1004
#> 17 20183    8270 PSYC     1004 PSYC 1004 added    1001 and 1002 -> 1003 and 1004
```

Your data with additional test cases

```r
data5 <- readr::read_table(
   "   YRTR    TECH_ID COU_ID  SUBJ    COU_NBR GENDER  RACE    sub_cou     status
   20173   108      217    MUSC    2231    Male    White   MUSC 2231   retained
   20173   108      218    MUSC    2281    Male    White   MUSC 2281   retained
   20173   8429     574    ECON    2201    Male    White   ECON 2201   retained
   20173   8429     720    BUSN    2120    Male    White   BUSN 2120   retained
   20173   9883     60     ECON    2202    Male    White   ECON 2202   added
   20173   3889     60     ECON    2202    Male    White   ECON 2202   dropped
   20173   15515    95     PHIL    1102    Female  White   PHIL 1102   retained
   20183   8207     478    ART     1102    Female  White   ART 1102    retained
   20183   8207     1306   ART     1130    Female  White   ART 1130    added
   20183   8207     1307   ART     2345    Female  White   ART 2345    added
   20183   8207     403    ART     1125    Female  White   ART 1125    dropped
   20183   8270     1306   PSYC    1001    Female  Black   PSYC 1001    dropped
   20183   8270     1307   PSYC    1003    Female  Black   PSYC 1003    added
   20183   8270     403    PSYC    1002    Female  Black   PSYC 1002    dropped
   20183   8209     1307   ART     2345    Female  White   ART 2345    added
   20183   8270     1306   PSYC    1004    Female  Black   PSYC 1004    added
   20183   8209     403    ART     1125    Female  White   ART 1125    dropped")
```

Comment: hello again! Thanks for the help! I did get this error when trying to run: ```Error in match.arg(.direction): 'arg' should be one of "down", "up"```

Comment: Hi, make sure you have the latest CRAN version of `tidyr` should be 1.1.2 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/index.html "downup" was implemented in 1.0.0